# Building DIY Spectrometer Foreoptics: Slit to Circular FOV

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, geometric-optics, lenses, sensor

I'm currently in the process of building a spectrometer, loosely following some of the instructions from the OpenLab DIY Spectrometer project, in order to further my understanding of sensor operation.

My understanding is that, because my spectrometer entrance is a slit, the field-of-view will be roughly linear. However, the spectrometers I've used thus far all had a circular Field-of-view using foreoptics. This is what I want to accomplish with this project.

I'd like to avoid using fibre optics if at all possible. My current understanding is that a collimating lens should be used as an outer lens on the foreoptics - what type of lens or lens pair would be best for this task? I also believe I would need a focusing lens between the collimating lens and the slit - would a plano-convex lens work best for this application?

Comment: Hamamatsu manfactures the world's smallest spectrophotometer,How does one design an tunable optical filter integrated with your spectrophotometer which exclusively filters intense coherent laser light while leaving the incoherent light background untouched? Thank you

Comment: Frank: While my question is relevant to the Hamamatsu microspectrometer line (ie. model c18666ma which has a linear entrance slit) you may want to start your own thread, as your question is unrelated to mine.

Comment: Hmm, seems like this should be a relatively straightforward question, but I guess it's not.